# find and replace registry key value batchfile

Tags: replace, find, key, registry

I need a code that could find a registry key and update its value. The below is the details:

In registry key SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} there are lot of sub-hive or folder if I can say like 0000 , 0001 , 0002 , 0003 and so on. Now I need to find a key called "Roamingpreferredbandtype" and need the value to be "2".
I need a batch file or vbs so that can deploy it via GPO.

Regards,
Suman Rout

Comment: Hey Suman, I just posted a similar solution here: http://serverfault.com/questions/829652/how-do-i-amend-the-roamingpreferredbandtype-property-of-my-users-wireless-netwo/829654#829654 - hope that does what you're after.

Comment: Failing that, there is a `bat` version here: https://communities.intel.com/thread/38634, though I've not tried that personally.